# Need help in extracting data from a plot

Tags: python, bokeh

Can someone suggest how to extract the data that we are showing in a bokeh server plot like we do in other tools like Tableau

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide an example of what kind of output you would like to get but I think you mean something like this:

```
bokeh serve --show script.py
```

---

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc

source = ColumnDataSource({'x': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'y': [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0], 'color': ['red', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue', 'orange', 'purple'], 'size': [15, 20, 15, 20, 15, 20]})
p = figure()
p.circle(x='x', y='y', color='color', size='size', source=source)
print(source.data)
curdoc().add_root(p)
```

This code snippet plots the data and returns a dictionary with all the data shown in the plot.